# How to use FindNext(...) to find the same value in original cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am still fairly new at vba in excel, so please bear with me. I have a program that more or less runs just fine, until I found a problem today. It starts right after the Do statement in the code (which I have the whole code below). I have it set my variables SO and dt to the values they need, then I have rngchk set to rngfull.Offset(, -4), set firstaddress to rngchk, and then I try to find the next cell with the same value as rngchk using findnext. But it isn't working. For example, if rngchk = 86913, and that is the only one on the sheet, FindNext finds 84193, and changes rngchk to that. Why is it not finding the next cell with the same value? And I hope that all makes sense.

```
Public Sub Shipped()
    
    Const WB_FULL = "Master Final SOs Testing"
    
    Dim wbFull As Workbook
    Dim wsShipped As Worksheet, wsfull As Worksheet, wsSandy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDwight As Worksheet, wsJohn As Worksheet, wsRack As Worksheet, wsBasket As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Dim rngFull As Range, rngSandy As Range, rngRack As Range, rngBasket As Range
    Dim rngJohn As Range, rngDwight As Range, rngchk As Range, rngShipped As Range
    Dim SO As Single, dt As Date
    Dim wsSimple As Worksheet, rngSimple As Range
    Set wbFull = Workbooks(WB_FULL)
    Set wsfull = wbFull.Worksheets("Full")
    
    With wbFull
        Set rngFull = wsfull.Cells(12, "F")
        Set wsRack = wbFull.Worksheets("Rack")
        Set wsBasket = wbFull.Worksheets("Basket")
        Set wsSandy = wbFull.Worksheets("Sandy")
        Set wsDwight = wbFull.Worksheets("Dwight")
        Set wsJohn = wbFull.Worksheets("John")
        Set wsShipped = wbFull.Worksheets("Shipped")
        Set rngRack = wsRack.Cells(6, "A")
        Set rngBasket = wsBasket.Cells(6, "A")
        Set rngDwight = wsDwight.Cells(6, "A")
        Set rngJohn = wsJohn.Cells(6, "A")
        Set rngSandy = wsSandy.Cells(6, "A")
        Set rngShipped = wsShipped.Cells(2, "A")
        Set wsSimple = wbFull.Worksheets("Simple")
        Set rngSimple = wsSimple.Cells(12, "B")
    End With

'Full
    Dim lastrow
     ' sort by SO and Line Number
    lastrow = wsfull.Cells(wsfull.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With wsfull.Sort
        With .SortFields
             .Clear
             .Add Key:=Range("F" & "11"), _
               SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
               DataOption:=xlSortNormal
             .Add Key:=Range("B" & "11"), _
               SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
               DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A" & "11" & ":" & "L" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
'Full


    Do
        If rngFull.Value2 <> "" Then
            SO = rngFull.Offset(, -4).Value2
            dt = rngFull.Offset(, -1).Value2
            Dim rng1 As Range
            ' add below last row
            Set rngchk = rngFull.Offset(, -4)
            Set firstaddress = rngchk
            Set rngchk = wsfull.UsedRange.FindNext(rngchk)
            If rngchk Is Nothing Then
                If rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "S" Then
                    Call SandyS(rngSandy, SO, dt, wsSandy)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "D" Then
                    Call DwightS(rngDwight, SO, dt, wsDwight)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "J" Then
                    Call JohnS(rngJohn, SO, dt, wsJohn)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "B" Then
                    Call BasketS(rngBasket, SO, dt, wsBasket)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "R" Then
                    Call RackS(rngRack, SO, dt, wsRack)
                End If
            ElseIf (rngFull.Offset(, -4).Value2 <> rngFull.Offset(1, -4).Value2 And rngFull.Value2 <> "" And rngchk.Offset(, -1).Value2 <> firstaddress.Offset(, -1).Value2) Then
                If rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "S" Then
                    Call SandyS(rngSandy, SO, dt, wsSandy)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "D" Then
                    Call DwightS(rngDwight, SO, dt, wsDwight)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "J" Then
                    Call JohnS(rngJohn, SO, dt, wsJohn)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "B" Then
                    Call BasketS(rngBasket, SO, dt, wsBasket)
                ElseIf rngFull.Offset(, -5) = "R" Then
                    Call RackS(rngRack, SO, dt, wsRack)
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: That's too much code. Can you provide an [mcve] please?

Comment: You need a `Find` before you can `FindNext` - is there one?

Comment: @SJR I just cut it down. Now it is only the variables being set, sorting once, and then the problem area.

Comment: Just curious, how come you can run your code in your question (which causing you ask: _Why is it not finding the next cell with the same value?_ ) while your code is not complete ? Your do has no loop, your findnext has no find and your sub has no end sub ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma I had my full code in there, but it was a lot, so I shortened it down to the main part that is causing the problem. So in my full code, it has a loop for my do, an end sub for my sub, but I haven't used find, since from all I've seen (which granted, isn't a whole lot), just using findnext should work fine here since I want to search for the cells after the current cell (if that makes sense). So I don't think I need to have a find to use a findnext. And it usually does work, but occasionally doesn't, which is what I find to be weird

Comment: Example : you set rngchk to cell A1 with value "test" ---> `set rngchk = range("a1")`. Then you want to find if there is a cell in the whole sheet with value "test" ---> `set rngchk = cells.findnext(rngchk)` by checking `if rngchk is nothing` ? AFAIK, `set rngchk = cells.findnext(rngchk)` will never get result where rngchk is nothing because you've already set rngchk to cell A1. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Now try to use FIND first. "test" value is in A1 and Z1000. `set rngchk = range("a1"): set rngchk = activeSheet.usedrange.find(rngchk) : fa = rngchk.address` then loop `do: set rngchk = activesheet.usedrange.findnext(rngchk): rngchk.select: loop while fa <> rngchk.address` the loop will have two iteration, and will select A1 and Z1000. If "test" only in A1, the loop will have one iteration and it select A1.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
Sub SimpleS(rngSimple As Range, SO As Single, dt As Date, wsSimple As Worksheet)
    Dim firstaddress As Range
    Set rngSimple = Sheets("Simple").UsedRange.Find(SO)
    'MsgBox firstaddress.Address
    If Not rngSimple Is Nothing Then
        Set firstaddress = rngSimple.Address
        Do
            If rngSimple.Value2 = SO Then
                wsSimple.Rows(rngSimple.Row).ClearContents
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Set rngSimple = Sheets("Simple").UsedRange.FindNext(rngSimple)
        Loop While Not rngSimple Is Nothing And rngSimple.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That did work for me, but that is not where the problem is. It is at the beginning of the code (now the last part of the code I posted), and it is finding something, but its finding a random cell it seems like, not the next cell with the same value

Comment: @Phantom12203 you can apply the same logic as my posted code set `.find` first if found assign the address, then your code, loop if there is still found value and the found value address is not the same as the `firstaddress`